# subprocess in racket

Tags: subprocess, stdout, racket

I am writing a program which needs communication between processes.

## my code:

```
#lang racket

(define-values (sp o i e) (subprocess #f #f #f "c://player1.exe" ))
(define count 10)

(for ([c (in-naturals)])
  (cond
    [(equal? count 0) (error "Province is empty!") ] 
    [else 
     (write "server" i)
     (set! count (sub1 count))
     (flush-output i)
     (display (read o))]))
```

## and the player1.exe code:

```
#lang racket
(define (interact notification)
  (cond
    [(eq? notification "server") (write "true" (current-output-port))]
    [else (write "false" (current-output-port))]))

(for ([c (in-naturals)])
  (interact (read (current-input-port)))
  (write "player" (current-output-port))
  (sleep 0.1)

  flush-output (current-output-port))
```

I am getting output if I run without loops. I am also getting output when only player is sending messages. But with both server and player sending messages the program gets hanged.
What do you think the problem is?

Comment: I've re-indented the code to be a little clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last line in your `player1.exe` file looks suspicious. `flush-output` is not actually being applied as a function.  Rather than

```
flush-output (current-output-port)
```

you probably mean:

```
(flush-output (current-output-port))
```

From a style point of view: the functions `read`, `write`, and `flush-output` all work on the current input and output ports by default, so you don't need to provide them.  Take a look at the documentation for those functions, such as [`flush-output`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/port-buffers.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._flush-output%29%29), and you'll see that it mentions that the `current-output-port` is its default.

So the line that we just looked at can be written as:

```
(flush-output)
```

More issues: don't use `eq?` to compare strings.  Use `string=?` instead.  The reason is that there can be two strings that have the same textual content, but for which `eq?` will still be able to distinguish the two.  e.g.:

```
kui $ racket
Welcome to Racket v5.2.1.
> (eq? "a" (string-copy "a"))
#f
> (string=? "a" (string-copy "a"))
#t
```